# Application with identifier 'xxxx' was not found in the directory devlaundry.onmicrosoft.com

Tags: azure, office365, office365-apps

I am new in Azure. I am trying to create  a desktop application like https://github.com/Cecildt/angular2-O365-desktop-app

Done Azure AD application Registration, then when I executed the command 'npm start' the Electron application is getting loaded and asked to sign in. While signing it it is showing the below error

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 6e7a1536-861e-4919-8193-d7568c5f6a37
Timestamp: 2017-01-24 07:16:49Z
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '41cs69e2-3912-4a4c-9e19-3198dfdefae8' was not found in the directory devlaundry.onmicrosoft.co
```

Am I missing something in settings? Please help

Comment: Could you check in Azure Portal that the app was registered properly?

Comment: @juunas  What  I have done is, in (https://dev.office.com/app-registration) App registrations-> Add. There Name: MyApp ,Application Type : Native, sign-on url : http:localhost:8088